# Get feed also returns activities from followers

Tags: getstream-io

I'm building an app where people can post items to a channel.
When I load the activities of a channel, e.g. `FeedManager::getFeed('channel', 2);` I also get the activities of the users I follow who did not post anything in that specific channel.

Maybe I don't understand something? But how to prevent this?

Comment: Does the feed 'channel' '2' follow other feeds? If so, then activities from those feeds will appear on the 'channel' '2' feed

Comment: No, a user follows a channel or another user. But a channel is not following anything.

Comment: app id please for further investigation ?

Comment: @Royw were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I removed the data for development purpose, but having the issue again. My app id is: 67378, It's happening in channel:1 now.

Comment: @ferhatelmas I have the same now with other feeds. Any updates on this?

Comment: Sorry, comment was missed. Let me check, I will come back to you. In the meantime could you explain how you post activities ? Do you use `to` targeting ?

Comment: @ferhatelmas I'm using the Laravel wrapper. If someone post something, it is post with the model and the ActivityTrait. The channels are added to the activityNotify method in the model.

Comment: Hi @ferhatelmas. I found out it looks like every feed with the id 1 is adding the follower activities. So, it happened to channel:1 and not channel:2. Now I also have a feed 'video', where the same error occurred on video:1 and not video:2. Checking from user id 1, which is following him self, user id 1. So maybe the issue has something todo with that?

Comment: Sorry, slow on this. This is a good finding. I will discuss this with the team and we might want to prevent this from happening (in follow request, return 400 if user follow herself).

Comment: Just checked we have this check in place for exact matched feeds, for example `user:1` can't follow `user:1`

Comment: @ferhatelmas, Ok I checked. Is has nothing to do with user following. User:2 is also seeing the items of user:1 in channel:1, but not in channel:2.

Comment: @ferhatelmas Any updates on this?

Comment: @Royw Sorry, for late again but your channel is following user feeds. For example; `channel:1` is following `user:57`, `user:1`, `user:27`, etc. so it pulls activities from these feeds. You can confirm it by checking `origin` field when you read `channel;1` activities. As a result, it's working as expected. You might have cleared data but not follows. Let me know if it's still an issue after this explanation.

Comment: Found this issue! 

So I added ```channel``` and ```video``` to the Laravel ```news_feed``` config, I thought this was necessary to work.  When you want to follow a user with the Laravel package, you can use ```followUser```, which is looping trough this news_feeds config and follow all these feeds, so also channel:1 for example. Channel:1 is in my project connected to the channel model and not the user model, but the news_feed config is meant to connect the User model. 

So, removing ```channel``` and ```video``` from the news_feed config fixed my issue. Thanks @ferhatelmas

Comment: I am happy, mystery is solved.